# redirects to php form action on submit instead of executing code inside of php file

Tags: php, html, forms

Newcomer to php here! I have two HTML forms that looks like this:

```
<form action="../includes/signup.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<!--inputs + submit button-->
</form>

<form action="../includes/login.php" method="post">
 <!--inputs + submit button-->
</form>
```

I am certain that the form action is correct as well as the content inside the PHP files themselves. However, whenever the inputs are submitted, the user is redirected to the PHP files themselves instead of the appropriate header(Location: "url"). So essentially, instead of going to the welcome.php page on a successful registration, the user is instead redirected to signup.php.

Basically, how can I make it so that the code inside the PHP file is executed and that user isn't redirected to the PHP files themselves?

Below is my PHP code:

```
<?php  
session_start();
$_SESSION['message'] = '';
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'personalproject');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

//if email is taken
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 0){
    //password confirmation 
        if($_POST['password'] == $_POST['confirmpassword']) {
            $name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
            $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
            $class = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['class']);
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=$email", $mysqli);

        $sql ="INSERT INTO users (name, email, class, password)" 
            ."VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$class', '$hashedPwd')";
        //redirect if successful
        if ($mysqli->query($sql) === true){
            $_SESSION['message'] = "You are in, $name!";
        header("Location: welcome.php");
        }else{
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Whoops. An error occurred, you could not be added to the database. Try again.";
        }

    }else{
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Your passwords do not match!";
    }
}else{
$_SESSION['message'] = "An account has already been made with that email!";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: the action="../includes/signup.php" shold point to the relative URL form the page where the form is, so for example /register or sth like that not to the php file itself. You have to think in this case from the website perspective not the directory tree:)

Comment: Hi! Yes, I tried that except it took me into the directory tree of /register instead :/. So the code in the php file unfortunately was not executed

Comment: Then there is Sth with your server config ;) what do you use? Apache? Nginx? Can you post the config?

Comment: my server is configured by MAMP

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple form validation structure you will have to apply this to your code.

PHP should check for the submit process, then validate form, then set a header to redirect.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//if submit is clicked.
if ($_POST['inputA'] == ''){echo "Cannot be Empty";}//the input to check is empty.
else{header("Location: anotherPage.php");} //redirect to your page.
}
?>
```

Your form should be like this.

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="inputA">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```